# How to set 2 speedometers on the same frame

Tags: python, wxpython

I have the following code working for one speedometer. By modifying the slider, the needle adjusts itself to the corresponding value on the speedometer. I created a second speedometer and slider on the same frame. While running the code I see only the two sliders and 2 small dots appearing- there no speedometer. How can I get the speedometer to show?

Thanks in advance.

```
import os
import wx.lib.agw.speedmeter as SM
import wx.lib.agw.speedmeter as SM2
import sys
import math


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        # creation frame
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,-1,"test2",size=(1200,1200))

        self.speed = SM.SpeedMeter(self, agwStyle=SM.SM_DRAW_HAND|SM.SM_DRAW_SECTORS|SM.SM_DRAW_MIDDLE_TEXT|SM.SM_DRAW_SECONDARY_TICKS,pos=(15,300),size=(35,-1))

        # Set The Region Of Existence Of SpeedMeter 1
        self.speed.SetAngleRange(-math.pi/6, 7*math.pi/6)

        # SpeedMeter In Sectors
        intervals = range(0, 201, 20)
        self.speed.SetIntervals(intervals)

        # Assign The Same Colours To All Sectors 

        colours = [wx.BLACK]*10
        self.speed.SetIntervalColours(colours)

        # Assign The Ticks
        ticks = [str(interval) for interval in intervals]
        self.speed.SetTicks(ticks)
        # Set The Ticks/Tick Markers Colour
        self.speed.SetTicksColour(wx.YELLOW)
        # We Want To Draw 5 Secondary Ticks Between The Principal Ticks
        self.speed.SetNumberOfSecondaryTicks(5)

        # Set The Font For The Ticks Markers
        self.speed.SetTicksFont(wx.Font(7, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))

        # Set The Text In The Center Of SpeedMeter
        self.speed.SetMiddleText("L")
        # Assign The Colour To The Center Text
        self.speed.SetMiddleTextColour(wx.WHITE)
        # Assign A Font To The Center Text
        self.speed.SetMiddleTextFont(wx.Font(28, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))

        # Set The Colour For The Hand Indicator
        self.speed.SetHandColour(wx.Colour(255, 250, 20))

        # Do Not Draw The External (CONTAINER) Arc
        self.speed.DrawExternalArc(False)



        #creation of slider 1
        self.slider=wx.Slider(self,-1,50,0,200,pos=(15,100),size=  (350,-1),style=wx.SL_AUTOTICKS|wx.SL_LABELS)
        self.slider.SetTickFreq(5,1)

        #binding the event of slider change
        self.slider.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER,self.sliderUpdate)


        ##############################
        # Second speedmeter


        self.speed2 = SM2.SpeedMeter(self, agwStyle=SM2.SM_DRAW_HAND|SM2.SM_DRAW_SECTORS|SM2.SM_DRAW_MIDDLE_TEXT|SM2.SM_DRAW_SECONDARY_TICKS,pos=(15,30),size=(35,-1))

        # Set The Region Of Existence Of SpeedMeter 2
        self.speed2.SetAngleRange(-math.pi/6, 7*math.pi/6)

        # SpeedMeter In Sectors
        intervals2 = range(0, 201, 20)
        self.speed2.SetIntervals(intervals2)

        # Assign The Same Colours To All Sectors 

        colours2 = [wx.BLACK]*10
        self.speed2.SetIntervalColours(colours2)

        # Assign The Ticks
        ticks2 = [str(interval) for interval in intervals2]
        self.speed2.SetTicks(ticks2)
        # Set The Ticks/Tick Markers Colour
        self.speed2.SetTicksColour(wx.YELLOW)
        # We Want To Draw 5 Secondary Ticks Between The Principal Ticks
        self.speed2.SetNumberOfSecondaryTicks(5)

        # Set The Font For The Ticks Markers
        self.speed2.SetTicksFont(wx.Font(7, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))

        # Set The Text In The Center Of SpeedMeter
        self.speed2.SetMiddleText("Km/h")
        # Assign The Colour To The Center Text
        self.speed2.SetMiddleTextColour(wx.WHITE)
        # Assign A Font To The Center Text
        self.speed2.SetMiddleTextFont(wx.Font(28, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))

        # Set The Colour For The Hand Indicator
        self.speed2.SetHandColour(wx.Colour(255, 250, 20))

        # Do Not Draw The External (CONTAINER) Arc
        self.speed2.DrawExternalArc(False)

        #set gauge to initial slider position
        #self.pos=self.slider.GetValue()

        #creation ofslider

        self.slider2=wx.Slider(self,2,50,0,200,pos=(15,415),size=  (350,-1),style=wx.SL_AUTOTICKS|wx.SL_LABELS)
        self.slider2.SetTickFreq(5,1)

        #binding the event of slider change
        self.slider2.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER,self.sliderUpdate2)


    def sliderUpdate(self, event):
        #get slider position and set it on speedometer
        self.speed.SetSpeedValue(self.slider.GetValue())

    def sliderUpdate2(self, event):
        #get slider position and set it on speedometer
        self.speed2.SetSpeedValue(self.slider2.GetValue())




if __name__=='__main__' :        
    APP=wx.App(0)

    frame=MyFrame(None,-1,'Test')
    APP.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show()
    APP.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate your speedometers you should use a different size than the current one.
Try for example `size=(100,100)` and you will see your speedometer appear.

In any case, you may want to use sizers to position your widgets and make them to expand or compress with the frame instead of using a static positioning with `pos` and `size`